# Field SCREEN_VIEW is not a valid dimension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm using firebase analytics with my android app.

I followed this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews?hl=en and now I'm tracking screens manually.

As you can see below it's working

[image]

Now I try to retrieve this data with the runReport-method https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/runReport as follows

```
{
  "dimensions": [{
    "name": "screen_view"
  },
  {
    "name": "firebase_screen"
  }
  ],
  "metrics": [{
    "name": "myMetric?"
  }]
}
```

I get the return message

> Field screen_view is not a valid dimension

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your reference of all the dimensions and APIs you can use: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

I think what you're having issues with is that the "screen_view" dimension doesn't exist. This is because if you go into your Firebase Console. "screen_view" is actually an EVENT.

So in your case, to solve, you would actually have to get the dimension "eventName" and FILTER for the "screen_view" name.

Comment: Thank you XTOTHEL! This topic is new for me. I assume it has to be something like this?

`"dimensionFilter": {
    "filter": {
        "eventName": "screen_view"
    }
}`

Comment: Almost! See this example here:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimension_filters it would be something like "filter":{"fieldName":"eventName", "stringFilter": {
            "value": "screen_view"
          }}